# Referencing factor names in R for ANOVA

Tags: r, anova

I'm relatively new to R and am trying to streamline an ANOVA script to read a set of factor names from a table, and perform statistical tests on the interactions between these factors.

My basic question is how to not have to manually write the name of factors when I call aov, like this:

```
aov2 <- aov(no_gap ~ Diag*Age, data=data)
```

But instead, to index a variable which contains the names of the factors of interest, like this (but this doesn't work):

```
aov2 <- aov(get(vars[5]) ~ get(vars[1])*get(vars[2]), data=data)
```

Here's my whole script:

```
#Load data
outName <- read_file("fileNameToWrite.txt")
data <- read.table(header=TRUE, "testDataTable.txt",stringsAsFactors = TRUE)

vars <- colnames(data)

# Make sure subject column is a factor
cols <- c(vars[1:2])
data[,cols] <- data.frame(apply(data[cols], 2, as.factor))

##
# 2x2 between:
aov2 <- aov(get(vars[5]) ~ get(vars[1])*get(vars[2]), data=data)
aov2 <- aov(no_gap ~ Diag*Age, data=data)
aov2 <- aov(apply(vars[5]) ~ get(vars[1])*get(vars[2]), data=data)
summary(aov2)
```

For reference, this is what "vars" looks like when evaluated:

```
> vars
[1] "subject" "Diag"    "Age"     "gap"     "no_gap"
```

Thanks so much for your help!!

Answer (score 0):

The argument `no_gap ~ Diag*Age` you are passing to `aov` is a **formula** object. You can create a formula object from `vars` as follows:

```
myform <- as.formula(sprintf("%s ~ %s * %s", vars[5], vars[1], vars[2]))
aov2 <- aov(myform, data=data)
```